# maven project not building through jenkins

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, jenkins, ejb-3.0

I am using jenkins for continuous integration of maven builds.
I am getting the following error

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [Projectname] : Cannot resolve reference Remote ejb-ref name=com.test/testclass,Remote 3.x interface =com.interfaces.ITestService,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session because there are 2 ejbs in the application with interface com.test.interfaces.ITestService. Some of the possible causes: 
> 1. The EJB bean class was packaged in an ear lib library (or through any other library mechanism which makes the library visible to all component modules), this makes all the component modules include this bean class indirectly. 
> 2. The EJB bean class was packaged in a component module which references the EJB, either directly or indirectly through Manifest, WEB-INF/lib. The EJB bean class should only be packaged in the declaring ejb module and not the referencing modules. The referencing modules .... msg.seeServerLog

following is my parent pom and web pom

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-ParentPOM</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Project-ParentPOM</name>

  <modules>
      <module>../Project-test1</module>
      <module>../Project-test2</module>
      <module>../Project-Web</module>
      <module>../Project-Service</module>
  </modules>  

</project>
```

here is web pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId>Test-Web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Test-Web</name>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>2.3.14</struts2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-cdi-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>Test-Common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>Test-Service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>test</groupId> <artifactId>Test-Service-Bkp</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> <type>ejb</type> </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just a quick few things off the top of my head before I parse that pom and your errors... What goal(s) is your Jenkins job invoking?  What version of Maven is Jenkins running?  In either case, I'd recommend invoking _install_ to make sure your module dependencies are accessible by the other module dependencies.

Comment: the goal of jenkins is to build every module as a single war which has dependency defined for each of other module. all the different module builds are success by maven install and both maven and jenkins are pointing to same .m2 settings.xml

Comment: hi Dan i am able to build and run on my local glassfish server but it fails on jenkins.

Comment: how did you solve this?